# Paginate table with HasMany relation in cakephp 3 beta

Tags: has-many, pagination, cakephp-3.0

I have advertisements table with (group_id,member_id,city_id) fields. This is my GroupsController->view method.

```
public function view($id = null) {
    $group = $this->Groups->get($id);
    $this->paginate = ['conditions'=>['group_id'=>$id] , 'contain'=>['Members', 'Cities']];
    $advertisements = $this->paginate($this->Groups->Advertisements);
    $this->set(compact('group' , 'advertisements'));
}
```

It generates this warning in addition to the true result.

```
Warning (4096): Argument 1 passed to Cake\Controller\Component\PaginatorComponent::validateSort() must be an instance of Cake\ORM\Table, instance of Cake\ORM\Association\HasMany given, called in D:\xampp\htdocs\project\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Controller\Component\PaginatorComponent.php on line 153 and defined [CORE\src\Controller\Component\PaginatorComponent.php, line 301]
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [**magic property getters**](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.ORM.Table.html#___get) return `\Cake\ORM\Association` instances, if you need the actual `\Cake\ORM\Table` object, use [**`Association::target()`**](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.ORM.Association.html#_target).

```
$this->Groups->Advertisements->target()
```